# Ruby on Rails Queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have this query in rails:

```
Extra.where("form_type = ?", 1)
```

However I would like to add a filter so the state also has to be Alabama. How can I do this? I tried this but it wouldn't work

```
Extra.where("form_type = ?", 1).and("state = ?", "Alabama")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hash to specify AND conditions:

Extra.where(:form_type => 1, :state => "Alabama")

Comment: is there a way i can do this so that it is not case sensitive? for example if in the database it is "alabama" instead of "Alabama", it still returns a result?

Comment: Jake, case-sensitivity is going to be dependent on the collation you used on your database tables.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot

```
Extra.where("form_type = ? AND state = ?", 1, "Alabama")
```

Comment: its not working for some reason.
`@extra = Extra.where("form_type = ? AND state = ?", "corporation", "Arizona")`
and i have it extracted like this @extra.each do |extra|

Comment: @Jake Did you try with an array: `Extra.where("form_type = ? AND state = ?", [1, "Alabama"])`

Answer (score 0):

And of course, the [meta_where](http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere/) solution:

Extra.where(:form_type >> 1 & :state >> % 'Alabama')

Answer (score 0):

```
Extra.where(:form_type => 1, :state => "Alabama")
```

Comment: is there a way i can do this so that it is not case sensitive? for example if in the database it is "alabama" instead of "Alabama", it still returns a result?

Comment: It's not case sensitive, with mysql at least. If for whatever reason it is for you, you could call `.downcase` on your state string.